# Why are all of my symbols not showing up on Latex editor?

Tags: latex

I am trying to create a symbols list. I have been provided a LaTex template from the university to write my thesis on. I am not well versed in LaTex, and need some help to determine why my list of symbols are not showing up in the compiled document.

I have a "List of Symbols Glosseries.tex" page that contains a bunch of sample symbols. I have added one test symbol at the bottom labeled "ET." However, in the compiled document, I only see 7 symbols, when in the "List of Symbols.tex" document there are 10.

This is the symbols code:

```
% This uses the glossaries package. With this package, you can include multiple types of lists, track page numbers if desired, and define new lists. More information can be found at the following sites: https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf and https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries


%*****************************************
%Define your list of glossary items below. Remember that the entries that you enter in this file will not automatically appear in the List of Symbols. You also have to reference the symbol in the body of your thesis by using the \gls command. 

%symbols
\newglossaryentry{deg}{name=$^\circ$, description={Degree}}
\newglossaryentry{grav}{name={1D}, description={Normal gravity environment}}
\newglossaryentry{wf}{name={\textit{f}}, description={Wear factor}}
\newglossaryentry{alp}{name={$\alpha$},description={Alpha}}
\newglossaryentry{theta}{name={$r_O$}, description={ecosystem respiration at reference temperature $T_a=0{^\circ}$C}}
\newglossaryentry{te}{name={$\tau_e$}, description={precision of the normal distribution of the likelihood}}
\newglossaryentry{q10}{name={$Q_{10}$}, description={multiplication factor to respiration with 10$^\circ$C increases in $T_a$}}
\newglossaryentry{phi}{name={$\phi$}, description={vapour pressure deficit response function}}
\newglossaryentry{del}{name=$\delta$, description={Transition coefficient constant for the design of linear-phase FIR filters which are used to take up space when testing the list of symbols}}

%this is the new symbol I am testing
\newglossaryentry{ET}{name=$\lambda$\text{E}, description={Latent Heat of Vaporization supplied to the atmosphere in watts per meter squared}}
```

Here is the code referenced in the "main.tex" which calls the list of symbols and generates a page with each symbol and description under the "list of symbols" title:

```
%**************************
%List of Symbols Section
%**************************
\singlespacing
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\printglossary[title=\centering List of Symbols, title=List of Symbols,style=mystyle,nonumberlist]
```

Here is the portion of the .pdf generated that is missing symbols:

[image]

Why is this happening? I appreciate any information provided.

Comment: Are you using all the symbols in your text? I think it only renders the one used, to declutter your symbols list.

Comment: oop, you are right.